# netem ratelimit stops limiting rate after short time and restores to default

Tags: linux, networking, rate-limiting, openvswitch

I have experienced a couple of times that netem stops working when I apply qdisc. This happened with both rate limit as well as loss.

For example, consider a scenario:
**Internet** <------>(eth1) **A** (eth2)<------> (eth3)**B**

PC A is connected to an internet access point via ethernet port eth1. PC B is connected to PC A via port eth2 of PC A. So, basically, PC A is a bridge that I configure using OvS. I apply netem rule on eth2 and expect it to be reflected on PC B.

Now, in PC A, I applied a rate limit on eth2 of 30Mbps with a limit of 1000 using the command:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth2 root handle 1:0 netem rate 30000kbit limit 1000
```

Then I ran the iperf3 server on PC B and test the bandwidth by running the iperf3 client on a different PC (say 'C' that is connected to the network). The iperf3 result is:

```
[  4] local xx.xx.xx.xx port 54838 connected to yy.yy.yy.yy port 5009
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  3.92 MBytes  32.8 Mbits/sec    0    185 KBytes       
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  3.38 MBytes  28.3 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  3.38 MBytes  28.3 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  65.6 MBytes   550 Mbits/sec  142    210 KBytes       
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   109 MBytes   918 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   203 MBytes   170 Mbits/sec  142             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   203 MBytes   170 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Initially, I am getting around 30Mbps but in the last two runs, the throughput is much higher than 30Mbps. I tried iperf3 again multiple times. Then it was fine. Why netem has this inconsistent behavior?

Another example where I cap rate to 50Mbps, the first iperf3 gave correct rate-limiting but one the second iperf3 attempt I got the inconsistent rate-limiting (as shown below):

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  6.05 MBytes  50.8 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  5.75 MBytes  48.2 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  5.75 MBytes  48.2 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  5.75 MBytes  48.2 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  29.8 MBytes   250 Mbits/sec  143    210 KBytes       
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   110 MBytes   920 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   109 MBytes   914 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   109 MBytes   915 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   109 MBytes   914 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   109 MBytes   914 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   599 MBytes   502 Mbits/sec  143             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   598 MBytes   502 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

After the fourth run, it appears that netem ratelimit is simply gone and the network is back to its default rate.

I have seen this behaviour when I introduce loss using netem. Please, any help to fix this or explain this inconsistent netem behaviour would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem.

PC A is the one acting as a bridge for two ethernet connections. Once we set OvS bridge, the internet is no longer available on PC A. By default, the OS (ubuntu 20 in this case) is configured to attempt connecting to the internet automatically after regular intervals on both eth1 and eth2. Because of OvS configuration, the connection attempt is bound to fail. After the failure notification, the qdisc is removed on the network devices. This results in the iperf3 behavior as described in the question.

The fix is simple, just go to the network settings and disable auto-connect on both eth1 and eth2, and save the setting. Once done, netem works fine.

Hope this helps those who may face this issue in future.